# handling multiple CALayer's drawing in a view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to implement a view having two layers on it. Then i want to do some drawing on these layers separately on press of some buttons.

I have implemented  delegate method:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
```

but problem is that this delegate is only fired with `[myviewclass setNeedsDisplay]` method(not by `[mylayer setNeedsDisplay]`)and then `drawLayer` gets called for view's root layer always.

I want it to get called for `mylayer` with accurate `context` so that i can do drawing on the specific layer using its context.

Please help how to achieve this.

Comment: What is the delegate of the layers? The view?

Comment: Yes thats another problem when i am trying to set the delegate to view it crashes app...dont know what to set as delegate.Currently i am not setting delegate to anything..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the delegate of the layer and implement the delegate method `drawLayer:inContext:` in it. Otherwise, the layer can't determine in which object it has to call that method.

Also, the delegate of the layer can't be the `UIView`, so you must use something else as a delegate.

You can use the view controller for example as the delegate of your layers. First, implement the method `drawLayer:inContext:` in the view controller. Then, set the view controller as the delegate of your layers.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // ...
    self.view.layer1.delegate = self;
    self.view.layer2.delegate = self;
}

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    if (layer == self.view.layer1) {
        // ...
    } else if (layer == self.view.layer2) {
        // ..
    }
}
```

Comment: hey got it man! thanks :) So easy just create your class with NSObject  for each layer and implement the delegate method there..setting the delegate as your class..